# how to assign/initialize the array of function pointers only when i call a function to do so

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  

int  (*(*ptr[2])[2])(); //arr of pointers to the array of func pointer
int (*arr_1[2])(int ,int);//arr of function pointers
(*arr_1[])()={add1, sub1};//add1 ,sub1 are simple functions returning int   
int (*arr_2[2])(int ,int);
int a,b, user_func_choice;
(*arr_2[])()={add2, sub2};
int lib_choice,user_lib_choice;

int main(int argc , char* argv[]) {
printf("enter the lib number\t 1:Lib1 , 2:Lib2 \n");
scanf("%d", &user_lib_choice);
lib_choice=user_lib_choice-1;
if(lib_choice==0){

printf("Welcome to lib1\n");
printf("enter func choice==> 1: Add , 2: subtract\n");
    scanf("%d", &user_func_choice);
    printf("enter the numbers.\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    int func_choice= user_func_choice-1;
    ptr[0]= arr_1;
            if(func_choice==0)
            {
            int sum1=(*(*ptr[lib_choice])[func_choice])(a,b);
            printf("sum1=%1d\n\n", sum1);
            }
            else if(func_choice==1)
            {
                    int subtract1=(*(*ptr[lib_choice])[func_choice])(a,b);
                    printf("sub1=%1d\n\n", subtract1);
            }
            else{printf("InValid Function/operator choice\n");}
       return;
    }
if(lib_choice=1){
int a, b, user_func_choice;
printf("welcome to lib2\n");
printf("enter func choice: 1: Add , 2: subtract\n");
      scanf("%d", &user_func_choice);
      printf("enter the numbers.\n");
      scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);             
      ptr[1] = arr_2;
    int func_choice= user_func_choice-1;
if(func_choice==0)
{
      int sum2=(*(*ptr[lib_choice])[func_choice])(a,b);
      printf("sum2=%1d\n\n", sum2);
}

else if(func_choice==1)
{
      int subtract2=(*(*ptr[lib_choice])[func_choice])(a,b); 
      printf("sub2=%1d\n\n", subtract2);
}
return;
}

else{printf("InValid library choice\n");
} 
return 0;
}
```

Every thing works fine here
But what i want is instead of hardcoding the initialization of library(lib1 or lib2) let user specify the number of libraries he want to intialize. Something like this

```
int main(int argc , char* argv[]){
printf("enter the lib number\t 1:Lib1 , 2:Lib2 \n");
scanf("%d", &user_lib_choice);

if(argc!=2){printf("please specify the library number as sencond argument\n");return 0;}
int lib_choice_cmd=atoi(argv[1]); 
if(lib_choice==1)
{
    lib1_init();
}

else if(lib_choice==2)
{
    lib1_init();
    lib2_init();
}
```

lib_init() is the function that will do the initialization process.If user specify lib num as 1 i will initialize only lib1. I did this for lib1, but this gives me an error

```
lib1_init(){
(*arr_1[2])(int ,int)={add1 , sub1};
}
```

And when i did

```
lib1_init(){
arr_1[0]=add1;
arr_1[1]=sub1;
}
```

This gives me a segmentation fault.Pleae tell me what is wrong

Comment: There is absolutely no added value in initializing "only when I call a function". The initialization is done at compile/load time and so has no run-time performance consequences. ...unless you want to assign _different_ functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do initialization when initializing, not later. Even given that, your syntax looks odd.

You can of course use plain assignment to each element:

```
void array_init(void)
{
  arr_1[0] = add1;
  arr_1[1] = sub1;
}
```

Comment: error: conflicting types for ‘arr’
main.c:6:7: note: previous declaration of ‘arr’ was here
 int (*arr[2])(int ,int);
       
main.c:26:13: error: invalid initializer
   arr[0]= add1;

Comment: i used this plane syntax before but it gives me this error

Answer (score 1):

```
(*arr[2])()={add1 ,sub1};
```

Unless that line appears on the same line as the function pointer array initialization, it is complete nonsense code.

You can initialize the array upon declaration like this:

```
int(*arr[2])(int ,int) = {add1 ,sub1};
```

Or you can assign an individual item, just as for any array:

```
arr[0] = add1;
```

In C, you cannot assign arrays to arrays, nor can you assign several array items on a single line. That is, you *can't* do `int arr[2]; arr = {1,2};`Function pointer arrays are no different than other arrays.

If you want to initialize the array in run-time, you have to either set each item one by one in a loop, or use `memcpy`.

Comment: when i did arr_1[0]= add1;  arr_1[1]=sub1; I'm getting  error: conflicting types for ‘arr_1’
main.c:6:7: note: previous declaration of ‘arr_1’ was here
 int (*arr_1[2])(int ,int);
       ^
main.c:7:11: error: invalid initializer
 arr_1[0]= add1;
what is wrong here??

Comment: @user123 The compiler is telling you that it doesn't make sense to allocate the same variable twice. Or possibly that you try to assign a function of the wrong type. You'd have to post the whole code or it is hard to tell the cause.

Comment: @user123 Just read this answer again. The first sentence in particular. That being said, what makes you believe you can execute code at file scope? And why are you using global variables in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I did not right understood the problem, but there is a syntax mistake:
if you declare a pointer to function array like this:

```
int(*arr[2])(int ,int)
```

you have to call the function like this:

```
(*arr[0])(some_int_stuff, some_other_int_stuff);
```

the mistakes are that the index must be smaller than 2, and you don't pass any parameter

Comment: `arr[0](some_int_stuff, some_other_int_stuff);` works fine.